# Possible to show a powerBI embedded report using the AD credentials of the logged in user instead of having to log in again

Tags: powerbi, azure-active-directory

Right now, when a user logs in to my app user Azure AD the user has to log in again to app.powerbi.com to view the report in the webapp. Is it possible to skip this second step and use the credentials from the AD login?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Embedded Power BI Report</title>
    <!-- Include Power BI Embedding JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/node_modules/powerbi-client/dist/powerbi.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="reportContainer"></div>

    <script>
        // Power BI report configuration
        var config = {
            type: 'report',
            tokenType: 0,
            accessToken: '{{ session["access_token"] }}',  // Access token from Flask session
            embedUrl: '',
            id: '',
            permissions: 7,
            settings: {
                filterPaneEnabled: false,
                navContentPaneEnabled: false
            }
        };

        // Embed the Power BI report
        var reportContainer = document.getElementById('reportContainer');
        var report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I had hoped something like this would have done the trick but I am getting a 403.